# Table expanding and different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, html-table

I have a problem with a table. 
The following JSFiddle will show, what happens. You need to open it with Chrome and with IE to
see the differences.

[JSFiddle open with IE and with Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/HZBQU/6/)

the code in JSFiddle is the following for the body of my HTML

```
    <table border="1">
       <tr>
        <th>data</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th class="hidden">nothing</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty hidden"></td>
        <td class="empty hidden"></td>
        <td class="" style="width:20px;"  rowspan="5">extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>dat</td>
        <td>test</td> 
        <td class="empty hidden"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dat2</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td class="empty hidden"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dat3</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td class="empty hidden"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Where the css code is the following:

```
.hidden{
visibility: hidden;

}

.empty{
    line-height:0;
}
```

The "extremely long" table data would represent data shown to the user, where the other table datas are just table datas ;)

What I want to happen:

I want the table to be represented in the Internet Explorer like it represents itself in chrome right now. The table data heights change in IE, but in Chrome they are fixed and the Table itself expands because of the long data.

I thought the rowspan command would help here, but I think I am missing some css commands.

Update:

To see what the tables look like, I made screenshots.

Chrome and how I want it to look like in every browser:

[image: Chrome Picture]

IE9 (but it also looks like this in IE11):

[image: IE Picture]

Update2:

for those who want to have a table which has the same number of table data in every table row, I updated the code and the fiddle. Same behaviour.

Comment: which one IE you use? working normal on IE9 IE10

Comment: I am using IE11 and IE9

Comment: I updated my post with screenshots, so you can see how it looks like for me

Comment: Your rows don't have the same number of cells (in order: 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1) therefore the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: New update with same number of cells. Therefore the behaviour shouldn't be undefined but it's also not the same for the browsers.

Comment: Are you sure this is tabular information? The way you *want* to present it (as shown in your 'Chrome' screenshot) makes it look as if nesting lists might be more appropriate, but honestly I'm struggling to understand any relationships between the data.

Comment: **I want the table to be represented in the Internet Explorer like it represents itself in chrome**...i see u expect lot from IE!! :)

Comment: @DavidThomas for this example, there is no relationship between the table and the data. For my project, it is. This example just shows my problem as short as possible. But if you want I can change the text just to show any relationship between table and data.

Comment: There's a chance it might lead to more useful answers (though there's also the chance it might lead to `ul` vs `table` commentary); but I think it would clarify the intent of the layout (because I can look at the pictures to see *what* you want, but not understanding *why* makes it very hard to offer HTML or CSS that can actually help you).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style>
.hidden{
   display:none;   
}
#top{vertical-align:top;}
</style>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="top">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>data</th>
                    <th>test</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>dat</td>
                    <td>test</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>dat2</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>dat3</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="" style="width:20px;">extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Still same problem. I dont want the data to manipulate the table heights

Comment: check now maybe will be helpful

Comment: Well this would work, but I don't really want to create a table in a table. If it isn't possible to reproduce the chrome behavior in IE I probably need to find a solution simmilar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define same number of columns on all lines, including on header.

You can use colspan, also.

Editing: my suggestion without bugging HTML code:

```
<div id="symetric-content-detail">
  <div id="table-content" style="float: left; height: 100%">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>data</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dat</td>
        <td>test</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dat2</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dat3</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="table-detail" style="width: 20px; float: left; height: 100%;">
    extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to reproduce a table with an unexpected behaviour. I suggest you to change your table to reproduce in the correct ways. Why you dont create two tables and float them side by side? By this way you dont will break any HTML or CSS rules.

Comment: It would be possible to create a symmetric table, like you want it, and add the class hidden to every table data I dont want to see. That way you would have the same result.

Comment: I edited the code to define the same number of columns on all lines. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th>dsfdasf</th>
    <th colspan="2">dfasd</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dsf</td>
    <td>fdsf</td>
    <td rowspan="3">extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg extreeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeoooooooooo oooooooomlyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooo oooooo oooooooonggg gggggggggggggg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dfasdf</td>
    <td>fasdf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&hgdgfh;</td>
    <td>&nhdgfhbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```